# Setting up a replicate slave MySQL fails when slave is disconnected

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL site and, for testing purposes, I want to create a replicate server.
I 've setup MySQL in Windows and configure it with instructions from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql).

Replication works, until I kill the Windows server. When I restart it (and the master server has applied some changes), replication no more works.

SHOW SLAVE STATUS returns errors such as `Could not execute Delete_rows event on table db.access; Can't find record in 'access`.

It seems that the replication slave cannot catch up with the main server unless they are connected. If the connection drops, then all changes are missing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are both servers the exact same MySQL version?

Comment: Yes, 8.0.16, Centos 7 + Windows